# Don't have the expected figure with ggplot()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame StatMNS [image: StatMNS] I plot statistic data (y) for each type of MNS (color)  on different areas (x)

```
ggplot(statMNS,aes(x=1:n))+
geom_point(aes(y=as.numeric(statMNS$v1qu_lidar)),size=2,col="skyblue")+
geom_point(aes(y=as.numeric(statMNS$v1qu_photo)),size=2,col="tan")+
geom_point(aes(y=as.numeric(statMNS$v3qu_lidar)),size=2,col="slateblue")+
geom_point(aes(y=as.numeric(statMNS$v3qu_photo)),size=2,col="tan3")+
geom_point(aes(y=as.numeric(statMNS$vmax_lidar)),size=2,col="navyblue")+
geom_point(aes(y=as.numeric(statMNS$vmax_photo)),size=2,col="tan4")+
geom_point(aes(y=as.numeric(statMNS$vmean_lidar)),size=2,col="skyblue4")+
geom_point(aes(y=as.numeric(statMNS$vmean_photo)),size=2,col="tan2")+
...+
labs(title = "Stat placette\n", x = "Placette", y = "Hauteur (m)", color = "Legend Title\n") +
scale_color_manual(values=c("max lidar"="navyblue", "max photo"="tan4",
                          "3e qu. lidar"="slatebule","3e qu. phot"="tan3",
                          "moy lidar"="skyblue4", "moy photo"="tan2",
                          "mediane lidar"="skyblue3","mediane photo"="tan1",
                          "1r qu. lidar"="skyblue","1r qu. photo"="tan",
                          "min lidar"="powderblue", "min photo"="lightgoldenrod1") )


statMNS2 <- gather(data = statMNS,key = TYPE,value = VAL,vmax_lidar,vmax_photo,v3qu_lidar,v3qu_photo,vmean_lidar,vmean_photo,vmedian_lidar,vmedian_photo,v1qu_lidar,v1qu_photo,vmin_lidar,vmin_photo)

ggplot(statMNS2,aes(statMNS2$readerName,VAL),color=TYPE)+geom_point()`
```

Firstly, I would like to show the legend
Secondly, I would like replace the x vector 1:n by the name of the area (column readerName of the dataFrame)

I try rearranging my data in StatMNS2
[image: StatMNS2]
but I have error (Discrete value supplied to continuous scale)

```
dput(statMNS)
structure(list(readerName = structure(list(X1 = "LBO_1", X2 = "LBO_11", 
X3 = "LBO_12", X4 = "LBO_13", X5 = "LBO_2", X6 = "LBO_3", 
X7 = "LBO_4", X8 = "LBO_5", X9 = "LBO_6", X10 = "LBO_7"), .Names = c("X1", 
"X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6", "X7", "X8", "X9", "X10")), 
vmax_lidar = structure(list(X1 = 167.4, X2 = 159.1, X3 = 163.5, X4 = 163.4, 
X5 = 160, X6 = 158.9, X7 = 153.8, X8 = 151, X9 = 157.3, X10 = 155.8), .Names 
= c("X1","X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6", "X7", "X8", "X9", "X10")), 
vmax_photo = structure(list(X1 = 148.8, X2 = 157.5, X3 = 161.1, X4 = 161.7, 
X5 = 158.1, X6 = 150.8, X7 = 141.6, X8 = 147.1, X9 = 155.1, X10 = 151.4), 
.Names = c("X1","X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6", "X7", "X8", "X9", "X10")), 
v3qu_lidar = ...
, .Names = 
c("readerName", 
"vmax_lidar", "vmax_photo", "v3qu_lidar", "v3qu_photo", "vmean_lidar", 
"vmean_photo", "vmedian_lidar", "vmedian_photo", "v1qu_lidar", 
"v1qu_photo", "vmin_lidar", "vmin_photo"), row.names = c("X1", 
"X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6", "X7", "X8", "X9", "X10"), class = 
"data.frame")


dput(statMNS2)
structure(list(readerName = list("LBO_1", "LBO_11", "LBO_12", 
"LBO_13", "LBO_2", "LBO_3", "LBO_4", "LBO_5", "LBO_6", "LBO_7", 
"LBO_1", "LBO_11", "LBO_12", "LBO_13", "LBO_2", "LBO_3", 
"LBO_4", "LBO_5", "LBO_6", "LBO_7", "LBO_1", "LBO_11", "LBO_12", 
"LBO_13", "LBO_2", "LBO_3", "LBO_4", "LBO_5", "LBO_6", "LBO_7", 
"LBO_1", "LBO_11", "LBO_12", "LBO_13", "LBO_2", "LBO_3", 
"LBO_4", "LBO_5", ...,
TYPE = c("vmax_lidar", ..., "vmax_photo", "v3qu_lidar", 
..., "v3qu_photo", "vmean_lidar", ..., "vmean_photo", "vmean_photo", ..., 
"vmedian_lidar", ..., "vmedian_photo", "v1qu_lidar",..."v1qu_photo", 
"vmin_lidar", "vmin_photo", "vmin_photo", "vmin_photo", "vmin_photo", 
"vmin_photo", "vmin_photo", "vmin_photo", "vmin_photo"), VAL = list(
167.4, 159.1, 163.5, 163.4, 160, 158.9, 153.8, 151, 157.3, 
155.8, 148.8, 157.5, 161.1, 161.7, 158.1, 150.8, 141.6, 147.1, 
155.1, 151.4, 146.6, 153.3, 160.8, 158.7, 156.3, 146.6, 140.6, 
142.6, 151.2, 152.7, 146.3, 151.5, 159.4, 157.3, 155, 145.2, 
140.2, 142.3, 149.3, 149.7, 147.8, 150.4, 160, 155.4, 154.1, 
145.2, 140.8, 142.9, 150.1, 151.4, 146.2, 148.9, 158.8, 154.2, 
153.2, 143.3, 140.2, 142.3, 149.2, 149.5, 146.3, 150.9, 160.1, 
156.3, 154.8, 144.4, 140.4, 142.4, 149, 151.6, 146.1, 147.4, 
158.9, 153.4, 153.7, 143.5, 140.2, 142.3, 148.8, 149.5, 146.2, 
146.3, 159.3, 151.1, 151.8, 142.6, 140.3, 142.3, 148.8, 150.1, 
146, 146.4, 158.3, 151.2, 150.8, 141, 140, 142.2, 148.6, 
149.1, 145.8, 145.6, 149.5, 149.6, 149.5, 138.8, 140, 141.9, 
148.5, 148.3, 145.1, 145.1, 155.4, 149.8, 149.1, 138, 139.1, 
141.3, 148.4, 148.4)), row.names = c(NA, -120L), .Names = c("readerName", 
"TYPE", "VAL"), class = "data.frame")
```

Thanks for you help

Comment: Please dput() your data so we could help you. Try to look for how to ask a question in SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've provided no sample data, it's hard to reproduce what you want. However I suppose your problem lies in your last line of the screenshot as you can keep `color` inside of `aes()` and as you just need `readerName` instead of `statMNS2$readerName`.

I used some sample data to make it work and provided you an example that might work with your data.

```
library(ggplot2)

# sample data
ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x=supp, y=len, color=dose))+
  geom_point(size=2)

# try on your data
statMNS2$VAL <- as.numeric(statMNS2$VAL)
ggplot(statMNS2, aes(x=readerName, y=VAL, color=TYPE))+
  geom_point(size=2)
```

Does it give you the expected result?

EDIT:
When using a short version of your data everything works fine. Does this example work for you? Start a new R-Session, copy and paste the whole code below and see if it works.

```
# short version of your data
statMNS2 <- data.frame(readerName = c("LBO_1", "LBO_11", "LBO_12", 
                          "LBO_13", "LBO_2", "LBO_3", "LBO_4", "LBO_5", "LBO_6", "LBO_7", 
                          "LBO_1", "LBO_11", "LBO_12", "LBO_13", "LBO_2", "LBO_3", 
                          "LBO_4", "LBO_5", "LBO_6", "LBO_7"),
           TYPE = c("vmax_lidar", "vmax_photo", "v3qu_lidar", 
                    "v3qu_photo", "vmean_lidar", "vmean_photo", "vmean_photo",  
                    "vmedian_lidar", "vmedian_photo", "v1qu_lidar","v1qu_photo", 
                    "vmin_lidar", "vmin_photo", "vmin_photo", "vmin_photo", "vmin_photo", 
                    "vmin_photo", "vmin_photo", "vmin_photo", "vmin_photo"), 
           VAL = c(
             167.4, 159.1, 163.5, 163.4, 160, 158.9, 153.8, 151, 157.3, 
             155.8, 148.8, 157.5, 161.1, 161.7, 158.1, 150.8, 141.6, 147.1, 
             155.1, 151.4))

# same ggplot call as above
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(statMNS2, aes(x=readerName, y=VAL, color=TYPE))+
  geom_point(size=2)
```

Comment: Hi, It doesn't work (Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale). Is it because my x value are a list of characters?

Comment: I edited my example as I suppose that your `VAL` are characters. Try `StatMNS2$VAL <- as.numeric(StatMNS2$VAL)` prior to plotting. Does it work now?

Comment: It doesn't work because you had different ways to write StatMNS2 and statMNS2, respectively. I updated my example now. Using statMNS2 works for me when using the data you provided.

Comment: ok. Thanks. Now i have this error:  ggplot(statMNS2, aes(x=readerName, y=VAL, color=TYPE))+
+   geom_point(size=2)
Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale. A library is missing, i don't really understand the error

Comment: Are there two ++ after your ggplot call? Remove one of them and try again. The code works for me, thus there shouldn't be any error.

Comment: When there's a library missing you may try `install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies=TRUE)`, which installs everything to make `ggplot2` work.

Comment: No there is only one +, the second one comes from the copy/paste.
With the simple data it's work fine. I will look inside my complete data. Thanks

Comment: Ok, then the problem must be in your data. Can you please add to your question what `str(statMNS2)` gives you? This might tell us where the problem is.

Comment: In fact in my data, readerName and VAL are lists. If I transform them in vector(c()) I have the expected figure.